# Throws SessionNotCreatedException While running test in Firefox

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am using below Version:

```
Selenium: 3.6.0
Mozilla: 56.0
Gecko Driver: V 0.19.0
```

When I run testng.xml file for mozilla firefox, it throws this exception:

> Log:
>   org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{marionette=true, binary=C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe, browserName=firefox, moz:firefoxOptions={binary=Optional[FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe)], args=[], legacy=null, logLevel=null, prefs={}, profile=null}, version=, platform=ANY}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
>   Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'b526bd5', time: '2017-03-07 11:11:07 -0800'
>   System info: host: 'LAPTOP-HS6HUVRH', ip: '9.124.94.212', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
>   Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:604)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:244)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:243)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:121)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:164)
>       at com.drlive.base.BaseTest.initApplication(BaseTest.java:126)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:523)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:224)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:146)
>       at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:166)
>       at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:105)
>       at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
>       at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
>       at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
>       at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>       at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

**Code:**

```
if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) { 
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox(); 
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
capabilities.setCapability("platform", Platform.ANY);
capabilities.setCapability("binary", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"); 
driver=new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
}
```

Comment: paste your code which you are trying to run.

Comment: if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
   capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
   capabilities.setCapability("platform", Platform.ANY);
   capabilities.setCapability("binary", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
   driver=new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);

Comment: Always paste your code by editing your current question description and updating that. I have suggested a solution just try it.

Comment: Yeah Sure. I will Take care of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have not updated the path for the gecko driver before initializing the FirefoxDriver() so

- **1st:** you need to download the geckodriver to run Firefox. [Download Link for Gecko Driver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)
- **2nd:** you can need to set the path for the geckodriver before initiating the driver.

So your code should look something like this.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "c:/path_to_driver/geckodriver.exe");
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Comment: System Property i am setting in @BeforeTest

Comment: Update your firefox to 57, use selenium 3.8.1 and use the latest gecko driver.

Answer (score 0):

Update to latest browser version use to solve this. If sticking to a specific browser version to long the geckodriver and selenium framework becomes incompatible. Update your firefox version and the error might